# Downsides to mixing boost and stl libraries in one project?

Tags: c++, boost, stl

I was wondering if it would be okay to use both the boost and stl libraries within one project? What are the potential downsides of doing so (besides code size which would obviously be one)? I'm creating a lot of wrapper classes for atomic types and low level data structures such as vectors, so I think that can help with some potential future issues, but I probably won't be wrapping EVERYTHING in my own container classes.

Comment: I would not create wrapper classes for standard language functionality. What do you gain by doing this? The semantics are precisely defined and a C++ must provide the classes and types. I think the times of broken compilers is hopefully over.

Comment: Well I'm creating a game engine and providing wrapper classes for base functionality provides me the flexibility of changing the implementation of say MyVector class without having to change it everywhere in my code base. So I can start off using stl::vector as my implementation for MyVector and then switch to using eastl or something else more easily.

Comment: Some of the assumptions which led to EASTL are outdated, some of them are still valid. There has been some discussion in the standard committee. If you are interested take a look at https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/sg14

Comment: Thanks Jens. Looks interesting. I do hope the committee starts taking the needs of game developers seriously since C++ really dominates the industry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't loose time with creating wrappers for the sake of it. Also boost is created as a kind of extention to stl, usually future versions of c++ take concepts proven in boost.

Of course, there is always a dissadvantage to using new libs: more api to learn, more dependancies to take care in your build process...

But if it is usefull, why recreate what can be just used. Boost is any way written in stl style.

Comment: Forgot to say that, fo example, stl algorithms accept boost containers without any issue. Just try to chose one container in order not to do a lot of conversions.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. And the reason I'm creating wrappers for things like vectors is mentioned in my comment response above. I think it can be very useful in my case.

Comment: If you use stl type iterators, and typedefs, you will be a compile away to switching to almost any C++ framework. No wrappers needed. If at some point you will want to change to a more exotic lib you can write the wrappers then. Until then typedefs will allow for easy switch, and iterators will ensure the code is compatable.

Comment: So your saying instead of creating "MyVector" class, I could just do "typedef std::vector MyVector"? If that's the case, what if I call a function of the stl::vector class that doesn't happen to be the function name of another implementation of vector? So if I do something like "myVector.at(0)" in my code but then switch my typedef to say boost::vector which say (hypothetically) has instead a function name of "myVector.atPosition(0)". Now I would have to go change all ".at(0)" to ".atPosition(0)".

Comment: Yes, it is always a matter of what you yive and take and when. In this case it is worth it, since most frameworks try to get in line with STL, and when they don't, a replace sould work. If this question was about, let's say, openGl and directX, my advice would be different.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the interesting discussion.